# Critical Points of a Function and Clasification HELP

Tags: calculus

Im trying so solve this one

Given the function
$$f(x,y) = 3x^3 + y^2 - 9x + 4y$$
I tried to find stationary points

$Fx= 9x^2 - 9, Fy= 2y + 4$

$0= 9x^2 - 9, 0= 2y + 4$

And I got confused here, and cant solve. Would apreciate any help, thanks

Comment: thanks for editing, Gerry Myerson

Answer (score 0):

This is correct so far, you just need to solve each of the equations you've ended up with.

So we have  $9x^2 - 9 = 0 \implies x^2 - 1 = 0 \implies x = \pm 1.$
And for the other equation $2y+4 = 0 \implies 2y = -4 \implies y = -2.$

So you have two stationary points, $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,-2)$.

Lastly, as a point about notation, you should write the partial derivatives with a *subscript*, e.g. $f_x, f_y$.